# Should I sell my stock and buy future instead if the future price is smaller than the current stock price?

Tags: futures

I am currently holding a stock.

I can see that the stock is trading at slightly above the future price.

I don't expect it to pay any dividend for a while.

Are there reasons that I should not sell my stock and then buy the future contract to retain my position? Assume I don't want to change my position.

I am trading in HK market if that matters.

Comment: transaction cost, also how far in the future are you comfortable with? which stock is this if I may ask?

Comment: @Jonat thanks, 2382 HK

Comment: check borrow rate you can get on this stock (some brokers let you lend your stocks)

Comment: @alexprice Indeed, my broker allowed me to join an automatical stock lending program. It automatically lends my stock to shorter and earns me a borrowing rate. So far my stocks aren't lent though.

Answer (score 2):

you should estimate cashflows in both cases, and to see what is more advantageous for you.
The cashflows are:

```
1) borrow rate cash if your stock is lent
2) interest rate cost if you intend to hold for a long period
3) potential dividends (if your holding period encompasses ex-div date)
4) cost of rebalancing future position if you intend to have exposure encompassing several future rolling dates
```

You could also consider deep in-the-money call (you would have leveraged stock position then).

Comment: In other words, the extra advantage of holding a stock is that it enables me to lend it to others for shorting?